# Is yt is weakly stationary?

Tags: statistics, stationary-processes

I have a model $y_t =0.5y_{t-1} + x_t +v_{1t}$ where $x_t=0.5 x_{t-1} + v_{2t}$
and $v_{1t}$ and $v_{2t}$ follow IID normal distribution ∼ $(0,1)$.
I need to show if $y_t$ is weakly stationary or not.

I know that if $y_t$ is weakly stationary then

1) $E[y_t]$ is constant

2) $Var(y_t)$ is constant

3) $Cov(y_t,y_{t-s})=y_s$

I have started with one and I have got

$E[y_t]$ = $0.5E[y_{t-1}] + 0.5E[x_{t-1}]$ however I am unsure how to precede.

Any help would be appreciate

Thanks!